# How do I count word occurrences in a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to read and display the number of occurrences of each word, the application should only count words that have more than one letter and not alphanumerical also turned to lowercase.

This is what I have right now and I'm stuck at this and have no ideas where to go from this.

```
public static void countWordNumber() throws IOException, CsvException

String pathFile1 = "src/main/resources/Documents/Example.csv"

 {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader(pathFile1)).withSkipLines(1).build();

        Map<String, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
        String[] line;


        while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            String words = line[1];

            words = words.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ").trim();
            words = words.replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ");
            words = words.toLowerCase();

            if (frequency.containsKey(words)) {
                frequency.put(words, frequency.get(words) + 1);
            } else {
                frequency.put(words, 0);
            }


        }


    }
```

I am trying to read the second index in the array list of the csv, which is `line[1]` , This is where the text of the document is located.

I have replaced all punctuation with spaces and trimmed it, also if there are more than 2 spaces I have replaced those with 1 and made it lowercase.

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
Title of document: XXXX

Word: is, Value: 3
```

EDIT: This is an example of my input file.

```
title,text,date
exampleTitle,This is is is an example example, April 2022
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to actually split the line of words and put the count of each one in the map?

Comment: How is being a "CSV file" relevant?  Are you supposed to equate a column with a word, or  can there be more  than one word per column?  If the latter, I'd suppose treating it as a CSV file to be a hindrance, not a help.

Comment: The csv file is like: title,text,date. I am only trying to count the words from the text column. @passer-by

Comment: Please provide an fictional example of the actual file data and format.

Comment: @hybridize - oh, ok. I see.

Comment: I have just edited my post and added a fictional example with the file type showed in the path towards the top. @DevilsHnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution does not look that bad. But for initialization i would replace

```
frequency.put(words, 0);
```

with

```
frequency.put(words, 1);
```

Since I am mising your Input file i created a dummy that works fine.

```
    Map<String, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> csvSimulation = new ArrayList<String>();
    csvSimulation.add("test");
    csvSimulation.add( "marvin");
    csvSimulation.add("aaaaa");
    csvSimulation.add("nothing");
    csvSimulation.add("test");
    csvSimulation.add("test");
    csvSimulation.add("aaaaa");
    csvSimulation.add("stackoverflow");
    csvSimulation.add("test");
    csvSimulation.add("bread");

    Iterator<String> iterator = csvSimulation.iterator();


    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String words = iterator.next();
        words = words.toLowerCase();
        if (frequency.containsKey(words)) {
            frequency.put(words, frequency.get(words) + 1);
        } else {
            frequency.put(words, 1);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(frequency);
```

Are you sure that accessing line[1] in an loop while iteration is correct? The correct reading of the input seems to be the problem for me. Without seeing your CSV file i however cant help you any further.

EDIT:

with the provided csv data an adjustemt to your Code like this would solve your Problem

```
.....
.....
    while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        String words = line[1];

        words = words.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ").trim();
        words = words.replaceAll("\\s{2}", " ");
        words = words.toLowerCase();
        String[] singleWords = words.split(" ");
        
        for(int i = 0 ; i < singleWords.length; i++) {
            String currentWord = singleWords[i];
            if (frequency.containsKey(currentWord)) {
                frequency.put(currentWord, frequency.get(currentWord) + 1);
            } else {
                frequency.put(currentWord, 1);
            }   
        }


    }
    
    System.out.println("Word: is, Value: " + frequency.get("is"));
```

Comment: I have added an example .csv file with an edit, it's at the bottom of my post, I hope that helps explain my issue better. @GJohannes

Comment: Now I see your Issue. Your words is still a single String with multiple words. You have to split alle your words in a line single Words. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex match to verify that `words` fits your criteria before adding it to your HashMap, like so:

```
if (words.matches("[a-z]{2,}"))
```

- [a-z] specifies only lowercase alpha chars
- {2,} specifies "Minimum of 2 occurrences, maximum of <undefined>"

Though, given you're converting punctuation to spaces, it sounds like you could have multiple words in line[1]. If you want to gather counts of multiple words across multiple lines, then you may want to split `words` on the space char, like so:

```
for (String word : words.split(" ")) {
  if (word.matches("[a-z]{2,}")) {
    // Then use your code for checking if frequency contains the term,
    //   but use `word` instead of `words`
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll see to implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

**Just another twist on things:**

Since it's been established (by OP) that the CSV file consists of `Title, Text, Date` data, it can be ***assumed*** that every data line of that file is delimited with the typical comma (**,**)  and, that each line of that CSV data file (other than the Header line) can potentially contain a different **Title**.

Yet, the established desired output (by OP) is:

```
Title of document: exampleTitle

Word: is, Value: 3 
Word: example, Value: 2
```

Let's change this output so that things are wee more pleasing to the eye:

```
-------------------------------
Title of document: exampleTitle
-------------------------------
Word           Value
===================== 
an             1
is             3 
example        2
this           1 
=====================
```

Based on this information, it only seems logical that because each file data line contains a **Title** we need to process and store word occurrences from column 2 **only for that data line**. With each word being processed we need to maintain the origin of that word so that we know what Title it came from rather than just carrying out a simple occurrence count of all column 2 words in all rows (file lines). This if course then means that the KEY for the Map which would be a word must also hold the origin of the word. This isn't a big deal but a little more thought will be needed when it comes time to pull relevant data from the Map so to display it properly in the Console Window or, to use for other purposes within the application. What we could do is utilize a List Interface of Map, for example:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> mapsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

By doing this we can place each file line processed into a Map and then add that map to a List named `mapsList`.

The provided text file contents example leaves little to be desired, never the less, it does help to some extent in the sense that, it comforts me to know that, yes, there is a Header line in the CSV data file and the fact that  the typical comma is used as the delimiter in the file .... and that's all. So more questions come to mind:

1. Can more than one file data line contain the same Title (Origin)?

   - If "yes", then what do you want to do with the word
     occurrences for the other line(s)?

     - Do you want to add them to the first established
       Title?
     - Or do you want to start a new modified Title? (must be a different title name in this case)
2. Will the second column (the text column) ever possibly contain a
   comma delimiter? Commas are very common in text of reasonable
   length.

   - If "yes", is the text in column 2 enclosed in quotation marks?
3. How long can the text in column 2 possibly get to? (just curious - it's actually irrelevant).
4. Will there ever be different CSV files to get Word Occurrences from
   which contain more than three columns?
5. Will there ever be a time where Word Occurrences will need to be
   derived from **more than one column** on any CSV file data line?

The method provided below (in the runnable application) named **getWordOccurrencesFromCSV()** is flexible enough to basically cover all the questions above. This method also makes use of two other *helper* methods named **getWordOccurrences()** and **combineSameOrigins()** to get the job done. These helper methods can be used on their own for other situations if so desired although the **combineSameOrigins()** method is uniquely designed for the **getWordOccurrencesFromCSV()** method. The **startApp()** method gets the ball rolling and displays the generated List of Maps into the console Window.

Here is the runnable code (be sure to read ALL the comments in code):

```
package so_demo_hybridize;

public class SO_Demo_hybridize {

    private final java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Started this way to avoid the need for statics.
        new SO_Demo_hybridize().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        String filePath = "DemoCSV.csv"; //"DemoCSV.csv";
        
        /* Retrieve the neccessary data from the supplied CSV 
           file and place it into a List of Maps:
        
           getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() Parameters Info:
           --------------------------------------------
           filePath:  Path and file name of the CSV file.
           ","     :  The delimiter used in the CSV file.
           1       :  The literal data column which will hold the Origin String.
           2       :  The literal data column which will hold text of words to get occurrences from.
           1       :  The minimum number of occurrences needed to save.   */
        java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Integer>> mapsList
                = getWordOccurrencesFromCSV(filePath, ",", 1, new int[]{2}, 1);

        /* Display what is desired from the gathered file data now 
           contained within the Maps held within the 'mapsList' List.
           Now that you have this List of Maps, you can do whatever 
           and display whatever you like with the data.           */
        System.out.println("Word Occurrences In CSV File" + ls 
                         + "============================" + ls);
        for (java.util.Map<String, Integer> maps : mapsList) {
            String mapTitle = "";
            int cnt = 0;
            for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : maps.entrySet()) {
                /* Because the Origin is attached to the Map Key (a word) 
                   we need to split it off. Note the special delimiter. */
                String[] keyParts = entry.getKey().split(":\\|:");
                String wordOrigin = keyParts[0];
                String word = keyParts[1];
                if (mapTitle.isEmpty()) {
                    mapTitle = "Title of document: " + wordOrigin;
                    // The Title underline...
                    String underLine = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(mapTitle.length(), "-"));
                    System.out.println(underLine + ls + mapTitle + ls + underLine);
                    // Disaplay a Header and underline
                    String mapHeader = "Words          Values" + ls
                            + "=====================";
                    System.out.println(mapHeader);
                    cnt++;
                }
                System.out.println(String.format("%-15s%-6s", word, entry.getValue()));
            }
            if (cnt > 0) {
                // The underline for the Word Occurences table displayed.
                System.out.println("=====================");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and returns a List of Word Occurrences Maps ({@code Map<String,
     * Integer>}) from each CSV data line from the specified column. The each
     * word is considered the KEY and the number of Occurrences of that word
     * would be VALUE. Each KEY in each Map is also prefixed with the Origin 
     * String of that word delimited with ":|:". READ THIS DOCUMENT IN FULL!
     *
     * @param csvFilePath           (String) The full path and file name of the
     *                              CSV file to process.<br>
     *
     * @param csvDelimiter          (String) The delimiter used within the CSV
     *                              File. This can be and single character
     *                              string including the whitespace. Although
     *                              not mandatory, adding whitespaces to your
     *                              CSV Delimiter argument should be
     *                              discouraged.<br>
     *
     * @param originFromColumn      (Integer) The The CSV File line data column
     *                              literal number where the Origin for the
     *                              evaluated occurrences will be related to. By
     *                              <b><i>literal</i></b> we mean the actual 
     *                              column number, <u>not</u> the column Index 
     *                              Value. Whatever literal column number is 
     *                              supplied, the data within that column should 
     *                              be Unique to all other lines within the CSV 
     *                              data file. In most CSV files, records in that 
     *                              file (each line) usually contains one column 
     *                              that contains a Unique ID of some sort which 
     *                              identifies that line as a separate record. It 
     *                              would be this column which would make a good 
     *                              candidate to use as the <b><i>origin</i></b> 
     *                              for the <i>Word Occurrences</i> about to be 
     *                              generated from the line (record) column 
     *                              specified from the argument supplied to the 
     *                              'occurrencesFromColumn' parameter.<br><br>
     *
     *                              If null is supplied to this parameter then 
     *                              Column one (1) (index 0) of every data line 
     *                              will be assumed to contain the Origin data 
     *                              string.<br>
     *
     * @param occurrencesFromColumn (int[] Array) Because this method can gather
     *                              Word Occurrences from 1 <b><i>or
     *                              more</i></b> columns within any given CSV
     *                              file data line, the literal column number(s)
     *                              must be supplied within an <b>int[]</b> array. 
     *                              The objective of this method is to obviously 
     *                              collect Word Occurrences contained within 
     *                              text that is mounted within at least one 
     *                              column of any CSV file data line, therefore, 
     *                              the literal column number(s) from where the 
     *                              Words to process are located need to be suppled. 
     *                              By <b><i>literal</i></b> we mean the actual 
     *                              column number, <u>not</u> the column Index 
     *                              Value. The desired column number (or column 
     *                              numbers) can be supplied to this parameter 
     *                              in this fashion: <b><i>new int[]{3}</i></b> 
     *                              OR <b><i>new int[]{3,5,6}</i></b>.<br><br> 
     *                              All words processed, regardless of what 
     *                              columns they come from, will all fall under 
     *                              the same Origin String.<br><br>
     *
     *                              Null <b><u>can not</u></b> be supplied as an 
     *                              argument to this parameter.<br>
     *
     * @param minWordCountRequired  (Integer) If any integer value less than 2
     *                              is supplied then all words within the
     *                              supplied Input String will be placed into
     *                              the map regardless of how many there are. If
     *                              however you only want words where there are
     *                              two (2) or more within the Input String then
     *                              supply 2 as an argument to this parameter.
     *                              If you only want words where there are three
     *                              (3) or more within the Input String then
     *                              supply 3 as an argument to this parameter...
     *                              and so on.<br><br>
     *
     *                              If null is supplied to this parameter then a 
     *                              default of one (1) will be assumed.<br>
     *
     * @param options               (Optional - Two parameters both boolean):<pre>
     *
     *      noDuplicateOrigins - Optional - Default is true. By default, duplicate
     *                           Origins are not permitted. This means that no two
     *                           Maps within the List can contain the same Origin
     *                           for word occurrences. Obviously, it is possible
     *                           for a CSV file to contain data lines which holds
     *                           duplicate Origins but in this case the words in
     *                           the duplicate Origin are added to the Map within
     *                           the List which already contains that Origin and
     *                           if any word in the new duplicate Origin Map is
     *                           found to be in the already stored Map with the
     *                           original Origin then the occurrences count for
     *                           the word in the new Map is added to the same word
     *                           occurrences count of the already stored Map.
     *
     *                           If boolean <b>false</b> is optionally supplied to this
     *                           parameter then a duplicate Map with the duplicate
     *                           Origin is added to the List of Maps.
     *
     *                           Null can be supplied to this optional parameter.
     *                           You can not just supply a blank comma.
     *
     *      noNumerics         - Optional - Default is false. By default, this
     *                           method considers numbers (either integer or
     *                           floating point) as words therefore this
     *                           parameter would be considered as always
     *                           false. If however you don't want then
     *                           occurrences of numbers to be placed into the
     *                           returned Map then you can optionally supply
     *                           an argument of boolean true here.
     *
     *                           If null or a boolean value is supplied to this
     *                           optional parameter then null or a boolean value
     *                           <u>must</u> be supplied to the noDuplicateOrigins
     *                           parameter.</pre>
     *
     * @return ({@code List<Map<String, Integer>>})
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("CallToPrintStackTrace")
    public java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Integer>> getWordOccurrencesFromCSV(
            String csvFilePath, String csvDelimiter, Integer originFromColumn,
            int[] occurrencesFromColumn, Integer minWordCountRequired, Boolean... options) {
        String ls = System.lineSeparator();

        // Handle invalid arguments to this method...
        if (!new java.io.File(csvFilePath).exists()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() "
                    + "Method Error! The file indicated below can not be found!" + ls
                    + csvFilePath + ls);
        }
        else if (csvFilePath == null || csvFilePath.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() "
                    + "Method Error! The csvFilePath parameter can not be supplied "
                    + "null or a null string!" + ls);
        }
        else if (csvDelimiter == null || csvDelimiter.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() "
                    + "Method Error! The csvDelimiter parameter can not be supplied "
                    + "null or a null string!" + ls);
        }
        if (originFromColumn == null || originFromColumn < 1) {
            originFromColumn = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < occurrencesFromColumn.length; i++) {
            if (occurrencesFromColumn[i] == originFromColumn) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() "
                        + "Method Error! The 'occurrencesFromColumn' argument ("
                        + occurrencesFromColumn[i] + ")" + ls + "can not be the same column "
                        + "as the 'originFromColumn' argument (" + originFromColumn
                        + ")!" + ls);
            }
            else if (occurrencesFromColumn[i] < 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ls + "getWordOccurrencesFromCSV() "
                        + "Method Error! The argument for the occurrencesFromColumn "
                        + "parameter can not be less than 1!" + ls);
            }
        }
        if (minWordCountRequired == null || minWordCountRequired < 2) {
            minWordCountRequired = 1;
        }
        final int minWrdCnt = minWordCountRequired;

        // Take care of the Optional Parameters
        boolean noDuplicateOrigins = true;
        boolean noNumerics = false;

        if (options != null && options.length > 0) {
            if (options[0] != null && options.length >= 1) {
                noDuplicateOrigins = options[0];
            }
            if (options[1] != null && options.length >= 2) {
                noNumerics = options[1];
            }
        }

        java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Integer>> mapsList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

        // 'Try With Resources' is used here to auto-close file and free resources.
        try (java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.FileReader(csvFilePath))) {
            String line = reader.nextLine(); // Skip the Header line (first line in file).
            String origin = "", date = "";

            java.util.Map<String, Integer> map;

            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                line = reader.nextLine().trim();
                // Skip blank lines (if any)
                if (line.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Get columnar data from data line
                // If there are no quotation marks in data line.
                String regex = "\\s*\\" + csvDelimiter + "\\s*";
                /* If there are quotation marks in data line and they are 
                   actually balanced. If they're not balanced the we obviously
                   use the regular expression above. The regex below ignores
                   the supplied delimiter contained between quotation marks. */
                if (line.contains("\"") && line.replaceAll("[^\"]", "").length() % 2 == 0) {
                     regex = "\\s*\\" + csvDelimiter + "\\s*(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
                }   
                String[] csvColumnStrings = line.split(regex);
                // Acquire the Origin String
                origin = csvColumnStrings[originFromColumn - 1];

                // Get the Word Occurrences from the provided column number(s)...
                for (int i = 0; i < occurrencesFromColumn.length; i++) {
                    /* Acquire the String to get Word Occurrences from 
                   and remove any punctuation characters from it. */
                    line = csvColumnStrings[occurrencesFromColumn[i] - 1];
                    line = line.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").toLowerCase();

                    // Get Word Occurrences...
                    map = getWordOccurrences(origin, line, noNumerics);

                    /* Has same Origin been processed before? 
                   If so, do we add this one to the original?   */
                    if (noDuplicateOrigins || i > 0) {
                        if (combineSameOrigins(mapsList, map) > 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    mapsList.add(map);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Remove any words from all the Maps within the List that 
           does not meet our occurrences minimum count argument 
           supplied to the 'minWordCountRequired' parameter. 
           (Java8+ needed)  */
        for (java.util.Map<String, Integer> mapInList : mapsList) {
            mapInList.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue() < minWrdCnt);
        }

        return mapsList;  // Return the generated List of Maps
    }

    /**
     * This method will go through all Maps contained within the supplied List of 
     * Maps and see if  the Origin String within the supplied Map already exists 
     * within a Listed Map. If it does then those words within the Supplied Map 
     * are added to the Map within the List is they don't already exist there.
     * If any words from the Supplied Map does exist within the Listed Map then 
     * only the count values from those words are summed to the words within the 
     * Listed Map.<br>
     * 
     * @param list ({@code List of Map<String, Integer>}) The List Interface which 
     * contains all the Maps of Word Occurrences or different Origins.<br>
     * 
     * @param suppliedMap ({@code Map<String, Integer> Map}) The Map to check 
     * against all Maps contained within the List of Maps for duplicate Origins.
     * 
     * @return (int) The number of words added to any Map contained within the 
     * List which contains the same Origin.
     */
    public int combineSameOrigins(java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, Integer>> list,
            java.util.Map<String, Integer> suppliedMap) {
        int wrdCnt = 0;
        String newOrigin = suppliedMap.keySet().stream().findFirst().get().split(":\\|:")[0].trim();
        String originInListedMap;
        for (java.util.Map<String, Integer> mapInList : list) {
            originInListedMap = mapInList.keySet().stream().findFirst().get().split(":\\|:")[0].trim();
            if (originInListedMap.equals(newOrigin)) {
                wrdCnt++;
                for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> suppliedMapEntry : suppliedMap.entrySet()) {
                    String key = suppliedMapEntry.getKey();
                    int value = suppliedMapEntry.getValue();
                    boolean haveIt = false;
                    for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapInListEntry : mapInList.entrySet()) {
                        if (mapInListEntry.getKey().equals(key)) {
                            haveIt = true;
                            mapInListEntry.setValue(mapInListEntry.getValue() + value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!haveIt) {
                        mapInList.put(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return wrdCnt;
    }

    /**
     * Find the Duplicate Words In a String And Count the Number Of Occurrences
     * for each of those words. This method will fill and return a Map of all
     * the words within the supplied string (as Key) and the number of
     * occurrences for each word (as Value).<br><br>
     * <p>
     * <b>Example to read the returned Map and display in console:</b><pre>
     * {@code for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     *      System.out.println(String.format("%-12s%-4s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
     *  } }</pre>
     *
     * @param origin      (String) The UNIQUE origin String of what the word is
     *                    related to. This can be anything as long as this same
     *                    origin string is applied to all the related words of
     *                    the same Input String. A unique ID of some sort or a
     *                    title string of some kind would work fine for
     *                    this.<br>
     *
     * @param inputString (String) The string to process for word
     *                    occurrences.<br>
     *
     * @param noNumerics  (Optional - Default - false) By default, this method
     *                    considers numbers (either integer or floating point)
     *                    as words therefore this parameter would be considered
     *                    as always false. If however you don't want the
     *                    occurrences of numbers to be placed into the returned
     *                    Map then you can optionally supply an argument of
     *                    boolean true here.<br>
     *
     * @return ({@code java.util.Map<String, Integer>}) Consisting of individual
     *         words found within the supplied String as KEY and the number of
     *         occurrences as VALUE.
     */
    public static java.util.Map<String, Integer> getWordOccurrences(String origin,
            String inputString, Boolean... noNumerics) {
        boolean allowNumbersAsWords = true;
        if (noNumerics.length > 0) {
            if (noNumerics[0] != null) {
                allowNumbersAsWords = !noNumerics[0];
            }
        }

        // Use this to have Words in Ascending order.
        java.util.TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new java.util.TreeMap<>();

        // Use this to have Words in the order of Insertion (when they're added).
        //java.util.LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new java.util.LinkedHashMap<>();
        // Use this to have Words in a 'who cares' order.
        //java.util.Map<String, Integer> map = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        String[] words = inputString.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9' ]", "")
                .replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String w = words[i];
            if (!allowNumbersAsWords && w.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                continue;
            }
            if (map.containsKey(origin + ":|:" + w)) {
                int cnt = map.get(origin + ":|:" + w);
                map.put(origin + ":|:" + w, ++cnt);
            }
            else {
                map.put(origin + ":|:" + w, 1);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```